# servlets / .jsp / sessons...confused

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am brand new to all of this, I like servlets and java on a whole so far but I'm having some growing pains.

Servlet Question: Just starting to learn servlets and I'm having an issue with Attributes/Parameters, Sessions and jsp.

Basically, I have a very basic
 form. My servlet code states:

```
println("Hello, " + request.getParameter("name") + "!!!");
```

..and my .jsp states:

```
<form action="SimpleServlet" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

So now what I need to do is take the last name input into this servlet, save it in session and then send it to a different .jsp that states:

'Hello, '

For example, if I input JIM into the servlet and it returns 'Hello, Jim!!!' in my first .jsp I would then need to click on a link on that page that re-directs me to another .jsp that takes the 'Jim' input and also displays 'Hello, Jim!'.

So I created a 2nd .jsp and have tried many different combinations of code on both to try and get this to work and I keep on getting null or screwing up the output of the first part of the form.

Could someone guide me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please post the code of your servlet also. I'm suspecting that your problem is with how you handle the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to show your last name JIM in multiple jsp pages you can use session to store your last name add following code in your servlet.

```
 String name  = request.getParameter("name");
 HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
 session.setAttribute("name",name);
```

then in all your jsp you need to do is put following scriplet where you want to print your name.

```
<%
  String name = request.getSession().getAttribute("name");
  out.print(name);
%>
```

Comment: This worked for me, I wrote the servlet part correctly but what I was doing wrong was the .jsp. I had written: request.getAttribute("name") and didn't have it grab the session data. A-doy on me. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly what you want using a single .jsp page, you don't have to create a different one. Just create a link that will POST different parameters to the same .jsp
But as an advice/direction to you, I think the first thing you must understand well is how can you pass and receive parameters and attributes to deal with at server side. Understanding what a request can carry has a huge importance in server-side development.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addon to Mitul's answer 
I'd advice you to use EL. It is a simplified approach.

Instead of `String name = request.getSession().getAttribute("name");` use
`${sessionScope.name}` It would give you the desired output.

The best part is that scope resolution is done automatically. So, here `name` could come from page, or request, or session, or application scopes in that order. If for a particular instance you need to override this because of a name collision you can explicitly specify the scope as